# Nativescript TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPackageManager' of undefined

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I'm following the nativescript plugin tutorial with the latest nativescript 6.7.x. When I get up to [step 3](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/building-plugins#step-3-write-your-plugin) I get the following error

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function 
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPackageManager' of undefined
System.err: File: (file: src/home/map7/code/nativescript-version-number/src/version-number.android.ts:6:46)
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace: 
System.err:     module.exports.push.../../../../nativescript-version-number/src/version-number.ts.VersionNumber.get(file: src/home/map7/code/nativescript-version-number/src/version-number.android.ts:6:46)
System.err:     at ./app/app.component.ts(file: src/app/app.component.ts:2:50)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
System.err:     at fn(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0)
System.err:     at ./app/app.module.ts(file: src/app/app.module.ts:1:0)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
System.err:     at fn(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0)
System.err:     at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.NativeScriptTemplate2/files/app/bundle.js:223:73)
System.err:     at ./main.ts(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.NativeScriptTemplate2/files/app/bundle.js:286:30)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
System.err:     at checkDeferredModules(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:43:0)
System.err:     at webpackJsonpCallback(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:30:0)
System.err:     at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.NativeScriptTemplate2/files/app/bundle.js:2:57)
System.err:     at require(:1:266)
System.err: 
System.err: 
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPackageManager' of undefined
System.err:
```

Here the affected code

```
import * as application from "tns-core-modules/application";

export class VersionNumber {
    get() {
        var PackageManager = android.content.pm.PackageManager;
        var pkg = application.android.context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(application.android.context.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        return pkg.versionName;
    }
}
```

**Update: Show where I'm calling .get()**

I call .get() in app.component.ts like so;

```
import { VersionNumber } from 'nativescript-version-number';
console.log("***** PLUGIN " + new VersionNumber().get());

import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Comment: When exactly you are calling `get()` on `VersionNumber`, may be you are doing it too early even before the context is ready.

Comment: @Manoj I'm calling it in app.component.ts, refer to update.

Comment: As I mentioned it's too early, try calling it on init.